# Does GAE/OpenID/OAuth support xmlhttp proxy?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid, oauth, http-proxy

Currently, my code would construct the GWT form, which user would submit directly to openId (or any authenticaiton service). Such a method works fine.

However, what if I had the gwt page server access the OpenID provider, is there a way/strategy for the server to mediate authentication between its client and the auth provider?

I wish to know the answers with respect to

- GAE as the proxy

and, regardless if GAE or Tomcat is the intended proxy, answers wrt

- Google Accounts
- OpenID
- OAuth

If so, it would be wonderful if someone could describe the installation strategy.